# requirejs and angularjs for non single page web apps?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have individual pages and initially I wanted to use angularJS because of data binding and the many other neat features. I also ended up using requireJS simply to help me manage my dependancies better as the list of javascript libraries I'm using is growing.

My question is using AngularJS with requireJS a no no for non single page web apps?

Answer (score 5):

It's not a no-no. You can definitely use angular on non-single page apps. You just will lose a lot of the functionality - ie the stuff between "pages". You app will essentially be recreated on every page.

I've used angular for a multi-page site (basically a product search engine), with each page being separate. I used GET and POST to transfer stuff across pages, but ultimately, I wanted to use angular for rendering the content on the page because it's just neat and clean.

Comment: I only mentioned this question because I was told by someone else on here that I was in for a "world of hurt" so I wanted to get others take on this because I would re-run modules on each page load.

Comment: nah. I've successfully used it for UI only and the code from my previous jquery-only+server-side version has decreased dramatically.

Comment: I have also noticed that a lot of my code has reduced too because I dont have to pick out element tags as much. Requirejs and Angular also helps me structure my code better.